# Ajax error result with struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have this configuration in struts.xml

```
<action name="updateAction"
    class="it.myApp.action.ajax.UpdateActionAction">
<result name="success" type="json"/>
<result name="error" type="json"/>
</action>
```

this is my Action class

```
...
try{
    act.update();
}catch(Exception e){
    Logger.print(MessageType.ERROR,"Update failed "+e.getMessage());
    return ForwardResult.ERROR;
}
return ForwardResult.SUCCESS;
```

at last, this is jQuery ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'updateAction.action',
    traditional:true,
    data : {
        'actionId': id,
        'actionName': name,
        'actionDescr':descr
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#act_'+id).html(data.name);
        $('#des_'+id).html(data.descr);
        $('#update_'+id).html(data.update);
        $('#userId_'+id).html(data.userId);

        $('#mdf_'+id).css("display","block");
        $('#save_'+id).css("display","none");   
        $('#diag_'+id).html(data.result);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("AZZ!");
        $('#diag_'+id).html(data.result);
    }
});
```

when action updates data with success, there aren't problems, ajax function executes "success" statement, but when action throws an exception, ajax doesn't execute "error" statement but "success" again...

why?

thanks advance

M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the request didn't generate an error, where "error" means the server returns an HTTP error code. The server response may indicate an error in a *different* way, e.g., an error property.

You can check the response code and contents using Firebug or something similar; if you're expecting something other than what it sends back, add some details to the question stating what it returns, and what you'd like to see instead.

The easiest option is to set the `statusCode` or `errorCode` of the result as detailed in the [JSON plugin docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON+Plugin#JSONPlugin-StatusandErrorcode). (Assuming that's the JSON plugin you're using.)

Comment: ...-.-'..yep...i'm feeling stupid...ajax doesn't follow "error" result of struts because is NOT a real error (404, 500 etc.) but it is a standard to redirect response, right?...at this point, i suppose it isn't a good solution to use Ajax error variable to manage this type of error...

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm having trouble making sense of this. Did you mean "the *response* itself wasn't an error"?

Comment: @jpaugh Probably, but I don't know what I was thinking five years ago.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Ging3r**,

Normally, JSP websites require a JSON plugin to encode/decode JSON messages.

[JSON.simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) is a good example of a JSON plugin. The [JSON.simple website](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) also provides tutorials for setting up JSON on JSP websites.

If you prefer using plugins specific to Struts, there are a couple of [JSON plugins for Struts2 on Apaches website](https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/home.html).

## Edit

I’m absolutely not an expert on JSP, and know nothing about the JSON Struts plugin you are using, although I know a little bit about [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

Nevertheless, the following two examples make sense for me. The examples are from the tutorial mentioned above.

### Example 1 - Server side JSP encoding

```
service.jsp: 
  <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
  <%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
  <%
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name","foo");
    obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
    obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
    obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
    obj.put("nickname",null);
    out.print(obj);
    out.flush();
  %>
```

### Example 2 - Client side XMLHttpRequest

```
client.html: 
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function createXMLHttpRequest(){
  // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest
  // Provide the XMLHttpRequest class for IE 5.x-6.x:
  if( typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined" ) XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0") } catch(e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0") } catch(e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") } catch(e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") } catch(e) {}
    throw new Error( "This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest." )
  };
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
}

var AJAX = createXMLHttpRequest();

function handler() {
  if(AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200) {
     var json = eval('(' + AJAX.responseText +')');
     alert('Success. Result: name => ' + json.name + ',' + 'balance => ' + json.balance);
  }else if (AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status != 200) {
alert('Something went wrong...');
  }
}

function show(){
  AJAX.onreadystatechange = handler;
  AJAX.open("GET", "service.jsp");
  AJAX.send("");
};
</script>

<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:show();"> Click here to get JSON data from the server side</a>
</html>
```

You can find more information about these examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples).

## PS!

You should also look into the solution suggested by [Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873739/ajax-error-result-with-struts2/7876799#7876799). He is far more experienced than me, and knows what he is talking about.

Comment: i'm using JSON  struts2 pluging wich i found in struts2 libs. isn't it enough? to create json response i followed this little tutorial [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)...to return the request, i think i wrong to set error response,right?