# Ajax json always returning error although json format in response is correct

Tags: ajax, json, cakephp-1.3, croogo

I have been trying to implement ajax login with CakePHP 1.3. I have a popup with a simple username/pass login.

Following is in my **views/elements/login.ctp**:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url'=>array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'), 'id'=>'user_login'));
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login'));
```

Following is in my controller **controllers/users_controller.php**

```
public function ajax_login() {

    $response = array('success'=>false);

      if($this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
         if($this->Auth->login()) {
            $response = array('success'=>"true");
         } else {
            $response = array('success'=>false);
         }
      }
        $this->set('response', $response);

}
```

The view for the above controller is under **views/users/ajax_login.ctp** has ONLY this line:

```
echo $javascript->object(isset($response) ? $response : array());
```

My Ajax has the following code:

```
function login_user(){

    var username = $("#UserUsername").val();
    var password = $("#UserPassword").val();

    if(username == "" || username == null || password == "" || password == null){
        alert("Please enter a username and password");
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"/users/ajax_login",
        type:"POST", 
        data:$('#user_login').serialize(), 
        dataType:"json",
        async: true,
    success: function() { console.log("success"); }, 
    error: function(msg) { console.log(msg); }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Now, everything seems to be working perfectly, however, this is always failing into the "error" callback and I dont know why. I've read all of the below links on stackoverflow, and none of them seem to be the issue!

[Weird JSON behavior when requesting a json file via $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463106/weird-json-behavior-when-requesting-a-json-file-via-ajax)
[malformed JSON while JSON is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915204/malformed-json-while-json-is-valid)
[Ajax error result with struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873739/ajax-error-result-with-struts2)
[json_encode creating a malformed JSON (with extra hidden character)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427775/json-encode-creating-a-malformed-json-with-extra-hidden-character)
[php json_encode not returning proper json encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518580/php-json-encode-not-returning-proper-json-encoded-string)

The ONLY thing I suspect is when I read the `console.log(msg)` of the error, I get the correct HTML response **{"success":true}** which is in correct format... BUT... the "responseText" I get something like this:

> responseText: "{"success":true}<!-- 0.375s -->"

so basically im guessing it's this "<!-- 0.375s -->" which is causing the json format to always fail in my ajax call. how on earth do i get rid of this?!... I'm no longer sure if this is a CakePHP issue, or and AJAX/JSON issue!... i've worked on both for over 5 years and now im stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the string `<!-- 0.375s -->` is breaking your code. Try to find out where it is comming from. Some steps:

1. What layout are you using to render this? Try `debug($this->layout)` in your Controleler to see which on it is. This may very well be in there since I don't see you setting the layout to `ajax` for example. Cake has this `ajax` layout, which essentially is an empty layout. It should not contain anything more than `echo $content_for_layout;` in CakePHP 1.3.
2. Check and be sure that your is "spitted out" UTF-8 encoded. This is a must for JSON.
3. Try replacing your current view code with `echo json_encode($response);` or to keep the trilateral check: `echo isset($response) ? json_encode($response) : '';` The JavaScriptHelper will to the same thing anyway.
4. This "strange string" may very well be some performance analyzer's "render time" comment. It is comming from somewhere within your app and as you can see it is a HTML comment. Lower your debug value in `Config/core.php` - I am guessing it is 3.

I am guessing that checking the layout and setting it to `ajax` or `empty` will solve your problem.

Comment: Mr Sabev, ure a life saver. Moreover,i really love the way you skimmed down the problem.From the above i tried all first 3 methods. unfortunately they did not work, as i am already using UTF-8 whether i like to or not(arabic content). I did, however thanks to you, started using good practice when it comes to Layouts (particularly i started using 'ajax' layout as good practice) although that didnt solve it!
but to "cherry-on-top" it, #4 was what was causing it. in my core.php i just simply changed the debug mode from Configure::write('debug', 3); to Configure::write('debug', 0);

poof! solved!

Comment: sorry, i can't vote up, but i approved the answer. reputation wont allow me to vote up. chherz :)